# Change the Order that Component Properties Display In

Tags: presentation

I have created a new rendering parameter to be used with a specific page layout. Everything is sync'd up but when I go to edit the Control Properties, my new section shows up below the "General" section. How can i make it so that my new section (Services Rendering Parameters Data) shows up first?

I was reading something that says to make a copy of the template instead of inheriting so that my fields will show first but I'm not sure I understand what that means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to set `Sortorder` of `Services Rendering Parameters Data` section to value lower than `General` section `Sortorder`.

1. Find `Services Rendering Parameters Data` section item in Content Editor
2. Make sure that `Standard Field` checkbox is checked in `View` ribbon
3. Find `Sortorder` field in the `Appearance` section
4. Set its value to `-100`.

[image]

Comment: Yes!!! This worked.I have been playing around with this for literally hours. You just saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Marek's answer was helpful but it took me a while to figure out which item to set the sort order.

Go to the `Template` that you have used for your `Rendering`. In that template, select the `section title item` and then set the sort under.

[image]